# Copy file with objective c to a smb share with different credential?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file, copy, smb

I'm currently using FSCopyObjectAsync to copy files. What I would like to do is copy files to a share, but with different credentials. One way is I can mount the specific share but I don't want the user to see the mounted drive. So is it possible to access a smb share without mounting? Thanks in advance.